# String concatenation in mapper class of a MapReduce Program giving errors

Tags: mapreduce, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

In my mapper class I want to do a small manipulation to a string read from a file(as a line) and then send it over to the reducer to get a string count. The manipulation being replace null strings with 0. (the current replace & join part is failing my hadoop job)

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
.....

public class PartNumberMapper extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
        private static Text partString = new Text("");

        private final static IntWritable count = new IntWritable(1);

        public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {

                String line = value.toString();

                // Read line by line to bufferreader and output the (line,count) pair
              BufferedReader bufReader = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(line));
              String l=null;
              while( (l=bufReader.readLine()) != null )
              {
                 /**** This part is the problem ****/
                  String a[]=l.split(",");
                  if(a[1]==""){  // if a[1] i.e. second string is "" then set it to "0"
                          a[1]="0";
                          l = StringUtils.join(",", a); // join the string array to form a string
                  }
                 /**** problematic part ends ****/

                        partString.set(l);
                        output.collect(partString, count);
              }

        }    
}
```

After this is run, the mapper just fails and doesn't post any errors.
[The code is run with yarn]
I am not sure what I am doing wrong, the same code worked without the string join part.

Could any of you explain what is wrong with the string replace/concat? Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: I think l = StringUtils.join(",", a); is incorrect. Change it to l = StringUtils.join(a, ',');

Comment: This is what I had referred to: [`join(CharSequence separator, String[] strings) `](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/util/StringUtils.html#join)

Comment: Are you sure that size of array a[] is >=2 every time? If not add one check.

Comment: Its always 2. But for few its `abc, ""` these are the values that I want to convert to `abc, 0`.

Comment: What InputFormat are you using that gives you multiple lines in the Text value?

Comment: @BinaryNerd "TextInputFormat".

Comment: Well TextInputFormat gives you a single line at a time into your mapper, it separates lines based on linefeed or carriage-return.

Comment: Shouldn't it be "a[1].equals " instead of "a[1] == ", but that's more on logic part. It will not cause your mappers to fail. If you look at logs/hadoop UI , what do you see as the reason for mapper getting failed. Its important to know the reason. Just doing code reviews here will not help.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a modified version of your Mapper class with a few changes:

1. Remove the BufferedReader, it seems redundant and isn't being closed
2. String equality should be `.equals()` and not `==`
3. Declare a String array using `String[]` and not `String a[]`

Resulting in the following code:

```
public class PartNumberMapper extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {

        private Text partString = new Text();
        private final static IntWritable count = new IntWritable(1);

        public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {

                String line = value.toString();
                String[] a = l.split(",");

                if (a[1].equals("")) {
                    a[1] = "0";
                    l = StringUtils.join(",", a);
                }

                partString.set(l);
                output.collect(partString, count);
        }    
}
```